# PHP MySQL PDO duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the below code, which works perfect. What i want to do is to check the refNo first to see if there are duplicates entries in MySQL. If there is then appear a warning message, otherwise appear a "ok" message. How can i do that with PDO? Any help?

```
(include("db.php"));
$SQLquery = "INSERT INTO mydatabase (refNo, name) 
             VALUES ('".$_POST["refNo"]."', '".$_POST["name"]."');";

$STH = $dbc->query($SQLquery);     

?>
```

edit: Hello guys, 
i prefer not to add primary keys. Is there any other way?

Comment: `refNo` to primary or uniq key maybe? `try(){...}catch(){...}`?

Comment: Why not just put a `unique` index on `refNo` and prevent duplicates from going into the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this without using a database level constraint, you'll need to do an extra SELECT statement before inserting into the table. But that gives you no absolute guarantees, as it might be two processes want to insert the same row at the same time and they will still succeed.

-- it'll look a little something like this; I'm not familiar with PDO but the structure should be the same

```
$selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM mydatabase 
             WHERE refno = '".$_POST["refNo"]."'";
$res = $dbc->query( $selectQuery );
if( $res->count() > 0 ) {
  // this result already exists; show error
}
else {
  // this result is new; put the insert query here
}
```

Comment: It's for training purposes, so i am ok with that! How can i do that?

Comment: I added a structure example; but I'm not familiar with PDO so you'll probably need to check the function names and exact approach.

Answer (score 2):

Set up refNo as a primary key. You could also create it as unique but that defeats the purpose - your reference number appears to be a unique primary identifier. Perfect choice for a primary key.

Further, change your query

```
try {
      $SQLquery = "INSERT INTO mydatabase (refNo, name) VALUES (:refNo, :name)";
      $SQLquery = $dbc->prepare($SQLquery);
      $SQLquery->bindValue(':refNo', $_POST['refNo']);
      $SQLquery->bindValue(':name', $_POST['name']);
      $SQLquery->execute();
} catch (Exception $e) {
      die("Insert error");
}

$count = $SQLquery->rowCount();

    if ($count == 1) {
    echo "Record added!"; 
    }
```

This binds the post value to prevent SQL injection too.

Edit: You *could* follow this up with `$count = $SQLquery->rowCount();` which will be 1 if the insert was successful, as it appears you've edited your question since you posted it for more info.

Comment: Wouldn't do it any other way

Comment: i prefer to use it as it is!

Comment: @MixalisPapoulakis : then you are extremely open to sql injection plus obsolete methods! :)

Comment: It's for educating purposes! I just want to keep it simple, that's all!